# What's the meaning of "Something out of"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read the sentence: "China's Government Is Like Something Out of '1984'."

From [https://www.realclearpolitics.com/articles/2020/02/20/chinas_government_is_like_something_out_of_1984_142444.html][1]

What's the meaning of "Something Out of"? Is this means "beyond 1984?"

Comment: It means something that would be reasonable to find in the novel *1984*, George Orwell's novel about a totalitarian regime of the future. (The book was written in 1948.) So it means that China's government acts like a totalitarian government that employs total surveillance to enforce absolute obedience to its demands, no matter how absurd, arbitrary, and contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OALD, one of the meanings of "out of sth/sb" is "used to show that sth comes from or is obtained from sth/sb",like:

> We'll get the truth out of her.